# Custom Cookie variable + Prestashop

Tags: prestashop

Prestashop

I am stuck we one problem for cookie. In prestashop 1.4.7 I create a custom cookie variable using  setcookie but when i am try to access and assign it on front-controller, I am not getting cookies set value.
here is my script:

**page: checkpostcode.php**

```
include(dirname(__FILE__).'/config/config.inc.php');
include(dirname(__FILE__).'/init.php');
global $cookie;

setcookie("is_postcode_checked", 1, time()+600, "/", "", 1); // Set the cookie in basepath
```

**On frontcontroller.php page :**
I am access it using `$_COOKIE` and assign it into smarty array.

```
'is_postcode_checked' => $_COOKIE['is_postcode_checked'] // Getting null value for cookie
```

**page: checkpostcode.tpl**

```
{$cookie->_get(postcode_checked_msg)}  // here get the is_postcode_checked value but
```

but I am not able to get `is_postcode_checked` variable value.

Answer (score 11):

In prestashop 1.5, global are deprecated.

To set something in the cookie :

In a controller :

```
$this->context->cookie->__set($key,$value);
```

Other file :

```
$context = Context::getContext();
$context->cookie->__set($finger_print,$result);
```

You can access to your value with :

In a controller

```
$this->context->cookie->key
```

Other file :

```
$context = Context::getContext();
$context->cookie->key;
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use Prestashop's own cookie class entirely rather than using the PHP `setcookie()` function. The class uses the "magic methods" `__get()`, `__set()`, `__unset()` and `__isset()` which should allow you to do this easily.

Try in your "page" code (not sure how you're executing this since it doesn;t look like an additional page controller):

```
global $cookie;

$cookie->is_postcode_checked = 1;
$cookie->write(); // I think you'll need this as it doesn't automatically save
...
```

And in your FrontController override:

```
global $cookie;

if (isset($cookie->is_postcode_checked))
    $is_postcode_checked = $cookie->is_postcode_checked;
else
    $is_postcode_checked = 0;
```

You can assign the variable $is_postcode_checked to a corresponding smarty variable to use in your template.

Comment: Do I have to to implement the first snippet in a php file? I cannot do it entirely inside the tpl file?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing this in the .tpl file but you can technically do almost anything in a tpl file.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to fetch the cookie from Prestashop cookie class, you should store it in this class too.

Use `die()` function in your controller, to find out is that cookie set

It is better, as Paul said, to use only global `$cookie` class to store and getting data.